# How to find the amount of possible piece configurations in the game of Checkers/Draughts?

Tags: combinations, game-theory, chessboard

All I know is that factorials are involved, I hope someone here can help me out.

These are the restrictions:

- 32 habitable squares
- Each square can be in one of five states: [white man, black man, white king, black king, empty]
- 12 is the maximum amount of any color of pieces (white men + white kings <= 12)

The calculation doesn't have to be absolutely perfect, symmetries can be ignored, I also want to figure out different kinds of combinations (for example given how long a game lasts on average how many different board positions one can expect etc...) so a general explanation of the formula/reasoning to be used would be preferred to the direct answer, although both will be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, checkers get removed from the board, so in any configuration, there are at _most_ 12 of each color.

Comment: @quasi Hi yes that is what I meant with "12 is the maximum amount of any color of pieces (white men + white kings <= 12)". Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: it was clear enough -- I just read it too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w,b$ be integers with $0 \le w \le 12$ and $0 \le b \le 12$.

Then for configurations having exactly $w$ white pieces and $b$ black pieces, the number of combinatorially legal configurations (even if not reachable by the rules of the game) is

$$\binom{32}{w}\binom{32-w}{b}2^{w+b}$$

Explanation:

- $\large{\binom{32}{w}}$ is the number of ways to place $w$ white pieces on an empty board.$\\[14pt]$

  $\large{\binom{32-w}{b}}$ is the number of ways to place $b$ black pieces on the board, given that $w$ positions are already occupied by white pieces.$\\[8pt]$

  Each placed piece can be either a King or a non-King. Thus, for each piece,  there are two choices, so we get a factor of $2^{w+b}$.

Hence, the total number of combinatorially legal configurations, for all possible values of $w,b$ is

$$\sum_{b=0}^{12}\sum_{w=0}^{12} \binom{32}{w}\binom{32-w}{b}2^{w+b}$$

which equals $2,308,487,701,529,742,077,825$ or approximately $2.3\times10^{21}$.

Of course, this is just an upper bound, since some of the above configurations, though combinatorially legal, can't actually be achieved by a sequence of legal moves, based on the standard starting positions.

As regards your question about the length of an "average" game, if two players have fixed strategies, all games they play will have the same length (and the same outcome), so in that context, average length is not very meaningful.

On the other hand, for the sake of exploration, suppose both players make random moves, consistent with the rules of the game (i.e., if jumps are forced, they must make such a move). Assume also that a player always converts a piece to King whenever it reaches the last rank. Now the concept of average length is meaningful, but the exact average, while it exists *theoretically*, is surely intractable to actually compute. Instead, write a program to implement such random games, and then run a simulation, to get an approximate value for the average game length.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I just thought of something and I'm not sure if it is already adressed by the equations and I am just not seeing it.

What about the fact that for example white kings are exactly identical to other white kings? Meaning that if you exchanged two white kings with each other you would have exactly the same board which should not count towards the total.

Comment: After thinking about it I think it is already accounted for, because 32 choose 12 is correct assuming all 12 pieces are identical like in my previous example. I hope I'm on the right track with my reasoning.

Comment: Each placed piece of a given color has two choices. There's no duplication since any other piece of that color is in a different location.

Comment: yep thanks for the clarification, I was on the right track but I'm not very confident in my math reasoning skills.

Answer (score 2):

**Acknowledgement:** my methodology was inspired by quasi's answer.

In a game of checkers/draughts non-king pieces cannot appear on the last row because they immediately become kings. This gives these white pieces and black pieces partially overlapping areas consisting of 4 squares in their own first row plus 24 shared squares.

Define:

- $w_1$: white pieces in white's first row.
- $b_1$: black pieces in black's first row.
- $w_m$: white pieces in the shared middle six rows.
- $b_m$: black pieces in the shared middle six rows.
- $w_k$: white kings, can be placed anywhere.
- $b_k$: black kings, can be placed anywhere.

Then the number of valid positions is given by:
$$\left\{\sum_{w_1=0}^4\sum_{b_1=0}^4\sum_{w_m=0}^{12-w_1}\sum_{b_m=0}^{12-b_1}\sum_{w_k=0}^{12-w_1-w_m}\sum_{b_k=0}^{12-b_1-b_m}\binom{4}{w_1}\binom{4}{b_1}\binom{24}{w_m}\binom{24-w_m}{b_m}\\\binom{32-w_1-b_1-w_m-b_m}{w_k}\binom{32-w_1-b_1-w_m-b_m-w_k}{b_k}\right\}-1$$

The $-1$ is needed because an empty board is not a valid position.

This evaluates to $500,995,484,682,338,672,639$.

Between 1989 and 2007 the [Chinook draughts player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_(draughts_player)) was developed. Linked on that Wikipedia page is a paper [*Checkers is Solved*](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-UA.0472-001/Checkers/checkers.solved.science.pdf) which confirms the above number.