# What is the number of positions of a 15 puzzle (4x4 board)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I wonder if someone can help me get a number for possible positions for this [childs game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) of 15 sliding pieces in a 4x4 board.

The normal game has numbers 1-15 that need to be sorted. The board I want to calculate has only three kind of pieces: 6 red, 6 green, 3 black, and of course the empty slot you can move through.

I referred to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240519/how-to-find-the-amount-of-possible-piece-configurations-in-the-game-of-checkers) and came up with this solution $\binom{16}{6}\binom{10}{6}\binom{4}{3}=6.726.720$. Does that look correct, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, and you should not divide by $2$ as in the ordinary 15 puzzle because it is possible to swap two pieces of different colours without changing the appearance of the rest of the puzzle – simply swap in addition two pieces of the *same* colour, effectively doing nothing at all with this second swap.